# iphone silhouette with scrolling image inside

Tags: html, css, iphone, image, overlay

I am trying to make a iphone overlay with a scrolling image inside to showcase mobile website designs, but the image isn't scrolling with the overlayed iphone on top is there something I am doing wrong and how do I fix it?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanl5660/Lao36z20/

---

```
<div>
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/iphone.png" width="370px" height="800px" style="position: absolute; ">
</div>
<div style="width:300px;height:700px;overflow:scroll;margin:30px; position: relitive;">

<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/mtest.png" width="98%" height="700px" alt="" style="margin-top:150px;margin-left:10px;" /><br />
<br />

</div>
```

Comment: i'm trying to edit your example, but seam like jsfiddle doesn't work well on my machine...
Anyway, the iphone should have a relative position, and a z-index:-1 (so that the above image is fully usable) and the above image should have position absolute with sensible margins related to the parent (the iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your html like this:

```
<div class="iphone">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/mtest.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then with CSS adjust the look :

```
.iphone {
    width:370px;
    height:800px;
    background:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/iphone.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size:100%;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    top:152px;
    width:293px;
    margin:auto;
    max-height:496px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.container img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Check this **[demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lao36z20/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've forked your example and twaked it a bit. By keeping inner content at constant width we can expand its container vertically and the effect is that like if we only moved scrollbar to the right. Please also note we can setup overflow behavior spearately for x and y axes.

Here's the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/74yh81s4/2/

and the code:

```
<div class="position: relative">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/iphone.png" width="370px" height="800px">
</div>
<div style="width:340px; height:472px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; margin:30px; position: absolute; top: 142px; left: 17px">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/mtest.png" width="295px" alt="" />
</div>
```

Best regards