# Displaying a scrolling image inside an iphone border

Tags: html, css, iphone

Basically, I want to display a screenshot of a website inside an iphone frame. And I also want this to be responsive.

I have a rough idea but wouldn't know the best way of positioning the image, I'd probably be using the 'overflow-y' css property and set it to scroll, and set the height, so that my long image will scroll inside the iphone frame, however my problem is getting the image to be the right size of the iphone. Is this some javascript witchcraft I'm yet to discover? thanks!

P.S. Don't say that 'this has been asked before and link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974767/iphone-silhouette-with-scrolling-image-inside) because none of the examples actually work so I can't understand it, and don't know if they're trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Would leave this as a comment, but not enough rep.

You should probably just try it out for yourself and then post your code if you're having any issues.

If you really have nowhere to start go to codepen and search for 'iphone'.